# how to avoid to include header files and static libs in bitbake package or image

Tags: image, header, bitbake

When I tried to bitbake my image from my recipe file, I don't want to include header file and static libs in the image, but they are always packaged in *.ipk, then installed in the image.

Here is my recipe

```
FILES_{PN} += "${libdir}/*.so"
do_install () {
install -m 0444 ${S}/lib/*.so ${D}{libdir}
install -m 0444 ${S}/lib/*.a ${D}${libdir}/local/lib
install -m 0444 ${S}/include/*.h ${D}${libdir}/local/include
}
```

I include shared libs only, and add headers and static lib to system root to build my app, but not want them in the package.
Any idea?

Comment: More information is needed. Which packages do the files, e.g. the static libraries end up in? The defaults would put *.a into ${PN}-staticdev. Does it end up there? If so, is that package being pulled into the image? If not, what is PACKAGES set to? Which version of OpenEmbedded is this?

Comment: e.g. if recipe is abc_1.0.bb, the generated normal package would be abc_1.0_armv7at2hf-neon.ipk. *.a and *.h files are included in it, I tried FILES_{PN}-static = "", *.a still end up there, then pulled into the image. BitBake Build Tool Core version 1.32.0

Comment: That is not the default configuration. What is FILES_${PN} set to (look at the output of 'bitbake abc -e')? There is still far too little information in this question to answer it